# Is there a way to have a discord.js bot communicate with a website?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, captcha

Essentially, I want to have it where if a user executes a command in a channel, it DMs them a link specifically for that user, with a captcha. If the user passes the captcha, give them a role.

I know how to implement captchas, I'm just having trouble with creating a link specifically for that user that specifically gives them a role.

Answer (score 0):

According to your post title, what you're looking for is to work with a captcha API. Since this is probably too complicated for me to explain here

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1Hv1vIL760&ab_channel=AnsontheDeveloper) which you may find helpful in creating a captcha bot.

Comment: I should probably phrase my question differently. I just need a bot to give someone a role with my bot via a website. I think it's possible because there is dashboards like MEE6.

Comment: I think it would be much more complicated to make that through your bot, but if you are using node there are ways to do it, like by using express or something else to host a website using the same node server... also if you want your users to actually be able to use the website you probably will need to pay for a domain, and get it hosted. which may not be what you're looking to do if this is a casual project. if you want, here's a link to the [express docs](http://expressjs.com/)